# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) xcode firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have installed pod file in my ios project to link firebase push notification. when I built solution i faced this error:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Pod file

[image: X]

Error message

[image: X]

Pod debug

[image: X]

rest of warning and errors

[image: X]

Pod release

[image: X]

Comment: Copy/paste the content of the podfile, don't put a screenshot. Also, copy/paste the FULL error on the linker command failed. It should give info about which file/framework is causing the issue.

Comment: you should open the project with .xcworkspace not the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: Thank you very much @Surely it's the issue exact!

Answer (score 2):

and welcome to Stackoverflow community :)

If you want to setup firebase on your pod, juste add

```
target 'Your_Project' do

    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Firebase/Core' 
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end
```

Then, on your ViewController, don't forget to

```
import Firebase
```

And, as it's mandatory, add a line for ex to the AppDelegate

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method:

// Use Firebase library to configure APIs
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Before that ,you have to create the app on the firebase console:

Go to the Firebase console.

Click Add project, then select or enter a Project name.

If you have an existing Google project associated with your app, select the project from the Project name dropdown menu.
If you don't have an existing Google project, enter a new Project name.
(Optional) Edit the Project ID.

Firebase automatically assigns a unique ID to your Firebase project. This identifier displays in publicly visible Firebase services, for example:

Default database URL — your-project-id.firebaseio.com
Default hosting subdomain — your-project-id.firebaseapp.com

I hope it will help you!

Have a good day!